# How to set access to file for Un-authenticated user?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have attached my project's folder structure. I have marked Login.aspx page and Scripts folder with Red color border. I have written required JavaScripts inside Scripts folder.

When the Login.aspx loads, Javascript error is coming. Error is shown below:

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Steria Browser - MKG)
Timestamp: Thu, 20 Oct 2011 08:46:42 UTC
Message: Syntax error
Line: 3
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:1642/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fCommonScriptFunctions.js
Message: Syntax error
Line: 3
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:1642/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fLoginScripts.js
```

After long analysis, I understood that the problem is due to un-authorised access since user is not completed authentication yet. But, I don't know how to override using web.config's location tag since both CommonScriptFunctions.js, and LoginScripts.js files are inside Scripts folder as shown in the attached screen-shot.

Any idea please....

Here is the screen-shot:

[image: Login JavaScript Error]

Answer (score 1):

you can use [location Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) in your `web.config` file

Comment: @Ashok kumar: can you mark the answer please if it was of any use?